# Помогите найти утечку памяти

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, com, wmi

Есть функция, которая делает WMI запросы, пример с MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa390422(v=vs.85).aspx. В моём варианте утекает память (в варианте с MSDN её утекает в разы больше), насколько я понял, это происходит как минимум в функции `CoInitializeEX`. Вот код:

```
bool TestWMI::getAnything(QQueue<QPair<QString, QString> > &records, QString WQLTable, const QQueue<QPair<QString, QString>> &field_caption)
{
    try
    {
        HRESULT hres;

        hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
        if (FAILED(hres)/* && hres != -2147417850*/)
        {
            throw "Invalid result!";              // Program has failed.
        }

        hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
            NULL,
            -1,                          // COM authentication
            NULL,                        // Authentication services
            NULL,                        // Reserved
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication
            RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY,    // Default Impersonation
            NULL,                        // Authentication info
            EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities
            NULL                         // Reserved
            );


        if (FAILED(hres && hres != RPC_E_TOO_LATE))
        {
            throw "Invalid result!";                   // Program has failed.
        }

        IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

        hres = CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_WbemLocator,
            0,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            throw "Invalid result!";               // Program has failed.
        }

        auto pLoc_deleter = [](IWbemLocator* p) { p->Release(); };
        std::unique_ptr<IWbemLocator, decltype(pLoc_deleter)> spLoc1(pLoc, pLoc_deleter);

        IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

        QString str = "ROOT\\CIMV2";
        if (lpRemoteName != "")
            str = lpRemoteName + "\\" + str;

        BSTR bstr = QStringToBSTR(str);

        auto bstr_del = [](BSTR b) {SysFreeString(b);};
        std::unique_ptr<OLECHAR, decltype(bstr_del)> sbstr(bstr, bstr_del);

        hres = spLoc1.get()->ConnectServer(
            sbstr.get(),
            NULL,    // User name
            NULL,     // User password
            NULL,                              // Locale
            NULL,                              // Security flags
            NULL,// Authority
            NULL,                              // Context object
            &pSvc                              // IWbemServices proxy
            );

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            spLoc1 = nullptr;
            throw "Invalid result!";                 // Program has failed.
        }

        auto pSvc_deleter = [](IWbemServices* p) {p->Release(); };
        std::unique_ptr<IWbemServices, decltype(pSvc_deleter)> spSvc1(pSvc, pSvc_deleter);

        hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
           spSvc1.get(),                           // Indicates the proxy to set
           RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
           RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
           COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,         // Server principal name
           RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,  // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
           RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
           NULL,                       // client identity
           EOAC_NONE                       // proxy capabilities
        );

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            throw "Invalid result!";               // Program has failed.
        }

        BSTR bstr1 = QStringToBSTR("WQL");

        auto bstr_deleter1 = [](BSTR b) { SysFreeString(b); };
        std::unique_ptr<OLECHAR, decltype(bstr_deleter1)> sbstr1(bstr1, bstr_deleter1);

        BSTR bstr2 =  QStringToBSTR("Select * from " + WQLTable);

        auto bstr_deleter2 = [](BSTR b) { SysFreeString(b); };
        std::unique_ptr<OLECHAR, decltype(bstr_deleter2)> sbstr2(bstr2, bstr_deleter2);

        IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
        hres = spSvc1.get()->ExecQuery(
            sbstr1.get(),
            sbstr2.get(),
            WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
            NULL,
            &pEnumerator);

        auto pEnumerator_deleter = [](IEnumWbemClassObject* p) { p->Release(); };
        std::unique_ptr<IEnumWbemClassObject, decltype(pEnumerator_deleter)> spEnumerator(pEnumerator, pEnumerator_deleter);

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            throw "Invalid result!";               // Program has failed.
        }

        IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
        ULONG uReturn = 0;

        while (spEnumerator.get())
        {
            HRESULT hr = spEnumerator.get()->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
                &pclsObj, &uReturn);

            if(0 == uReturn)
            {
                break;
            }

            auto pclsObj_deleter = [](IWbemClassObject* p) { p->Release(); };
            std::unique_ptr<IWbemClassObject, decltype(pclsObj_deleter)> spclsObj(pclsObj, pclsObj_deleter);

            VARIANT vtProp;

            for (auto &k : field_caption)
            {
                if (WBEM_S_NO_ERROR == spclsObj.get()->Get(reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(k.first.utf16()), 0, &vtProp, 0, 0))
                {
                    records.enqueue(QPair<QString, QString>(k.second, QString::fromStdWString(vtProp.bstrVal)));
                    VariantClear(&vtProp);
                }
            }
        }

        spLoc1 = nullptr;
        spSvc1 = nullptr;
        sbstr = nullptr;
        sbstr1 = nullptr;
        sbstr2 = nullptr;
        spEnumerator = nullptr;
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    catch (const char* e)
    {
        qDebug() << "Exception in WMI";
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Вызов функции:

```
TestWMI t(lpRemoteName);
QQueue<QPair<QString, QString>> q;
QQueue<QPair<QString, QString>> par;

par.enqueue(QPair<QString, QString>(QString("Name"), QString("Имя")));
par.enqueue(QPair<QString, QString>(QString("Description"), QString("Описание")));
par.enqueue(QPair<QString, QString>(QString("SerialNumber"), QString("Серийный номер")));
t.getAnything(q, "Win32_Bios", par);
```

Comment: В строчке `if (FAILED(hres && hres != RPC_E_TOO_LATE))` видимо есть опечатка, правильнее будет `if (FAILED(hres) && (RPC_E_TOO_LATE != hres))`. `VARIANT` перед использованием надо инициализировать вызвав `VariantInit`, а после вызвать `VariantClear` **на кажом цикле**. Отсутствие вызова `VariantClear` на каждой итерации как раз похоже на утечку.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что утечка есть?

Comment: Вызывал в цикле функцию пару десятков тысяч раз (на 40 мб выросла), проверял с помощью dr memory, он тоже говорит, что утечки есть

Comment: @VTT VariantInit вызывается при передаче VARIANT в Get, как я думаю, а значит VariantClear и вправду надо вызывать каждый раз в цикле, исправил

Comment: Еще надо проверять результат [IWbemClassObject::Get method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391442(v=vs.85).aspx): "When successful, this parameter is assigned the correct type and value for the qualifier, and the VariantInit function is called on pVal. It is the responsibility of the caller to call VariantClear on pVal when the value is not needed. If there is an error, the value that pVal points to is not modified. If an uninitialized pVal value is passed to the method, then the caller must check the return value of the method, and call VariantClear only when the method succeeds."

Comment: @VTT А почему нельзя всегда вызывать VariantClear? Я проверил, если их несколько подряд вызвать, то никаких вылетов не происходит. И память всё ещё утекает, хотя это наверняка уменьшило объём теряемой памяти.

Comment: А потому, что `VariantClear` следует вызывать только когда была инициализация `VariantInit`. Иначе в `vtProp` будет мусор и вызов  `VariantClear` приведет к неопределенному поведению. Правда метод Get как-то хитро работает, обычно поведение функций с вариантом более прямолинейное.

Comment: @VTT Хорошо, код подправил, но память всё ещё утекает

Comment: Еще вот это `reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(k.first.utf16())` выглядит подозрительно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68318/discussion-between---and-vtt).